# Could intersystems cache global nodes be ordered by the second node?

Tags: caching, global, m, intersystems

I want to sort the string(or number) by the second global nodes(the `$o` is ordered by the first node then second node ...but i don't care about the first node, i just want the data sorted by the second node, just ignore the first node). as if i want to sort the global  `^G("3","2")` `^G("1","3")` `^G("2","1")` . the global would be ordered by the second node, from small to large ,like `^G("2","1")` `^G("3","2")` `^G("1","3")`, so is there any existing function to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

no. Usually you would get that result by creating an index on the second node and then order by that.